# Factorize a scatter matrix $S$ as $S=XAX^T$

Tags: matrices, summation

I have trouble working out this seemingly simple problem:

Let $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ be some data and

$$
\mathbf{S}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{
  \sum_{j=1}^{n}{
    (\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)^T
  }
}
$$

be a $d\times d$ scatter matrix where $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for $i \in \{1,\cdots, n \}$.

I want to get rid of the summations and express the scatter matrix $\mathbf{S}$ in terms of $\mathbf{X}$ as follows:
$$
\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}^T
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is some $n\times n$ matrix.

So far I have this:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{S} =& 
  \sum_{i=1}^{n}{
  \sum_{j=1}^{n}{
      \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i^T
    + \mathbf{x}_j\mathbf{x}_j^T
    - \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_j^T
    - \mathbf{x}_j\mathbf{x}_i^T
  }
} \\
 =& 2 \mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T -
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{
  \sum_{j=1}^{n}{
    \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_j^T
    + \mathbf{x}_j\mathbf{x}_i^T
  }
} \\
 =& 2 \mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T -
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{
  \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i^T
} -
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{
  \sum_{j=1,i\neq j}^{n}{
    \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_j^T
    + \mathbf{x}_j\mathbf{x}_i^T
  }
} 
\\
 =& \mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T -
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{
  \sum_{j=1,i\neq j}^{n}{
    \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_j^T
    + \mathbf{x}_j\mathbf{x}_i^T
  }
} 
\end{align}

I am stuck. How do I get rid of these summations? Are there any tricks I can use to make the expression simpler?

Edit: Is there a way to incorporate the summations into the $A$ matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e = (1,\dots,1) \in \Bbb R^n$, and let $\otimes$ denote the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). A nice way to produce a matrix that contains every $x_i - x_j$ as its columns is to take
$$
P = X \otimes e^T = \pmatrix{x_1 e^T &x_2 e^T &\cdots & x_ne^T},\\
Q = e^T \otimes X = \pmatrix{X&X&\cdots&X},\\
M = P - Q.
$$
From there, the matrix you're looking for can be expressed as 
$$
S = MM^T = [P - Q][P-Q]^T = \\
PP^T + QQ^T - PQ^T - QP^T =\\
n\,XX^T + n\,XX^T - (Xe) \otimes (Xe)^T - (Xe)^T \otimes (Xe) =\\
2nXX^T - 2(Xe)(Xe)^T =\\
2nXX^T - 2Xee^TX^T = \\
X[2nI - 2ee^T]X^T.
$$
So, $A = 2nI - 2ee^T$ seems to work.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer! How did you go from $(Xe) \otimes (Xe)^T$ to $Xe$? I have looked at the properties of the Kronecker product (https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/kronthesisschaecke04.pdf) but could not find a solution.

Comment: For column vectors $u,v$, note that $u \otimes v^T = v^T \otimes u = uv^T$.