# prove that covariance matrix can be expressed as $XCX^\top$ with C is centering matrix

Tags: matrices, summation, covariance, linear-regression, projection-matrices

How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-\bar{x}_n)(x_i-\bar{x}_n)^2}$ can be expressed as $XCX^\top$ with $C =  I_n -\frac{1}{n} 11^\top $?

I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429667/factorize-a-scatter-matrix-s-as-s-xaxt) answer but it did not lead me anywhere because I couldn't grasp the concept of the Kronecker product and also its beyond the syllabus.

Comment: if '$X$' is not a vector then the statement that $XCX^T$ gives $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-\bar{x}_n)(x_i-\bar{x}_n)^2}$ is not true.  So I assume $X$ is a vector... further, the statement really should be $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-\mu)(x_i-\mu)^2}$... putting a bar over $x_n$ does not make much sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplication by centering matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544437/multiplication-by-centering-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Expressions involving sums of indexed vectors can be very difficult to comprehend. My "goto" identity for unraveling them is the following
$$\eqalign{
S
 &= \sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^N A_{mn}\,y_m\,z_n^T \\
 &= \sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^N (Ye_m)A_{mn}(Ze_n)^T \\
 &= Y\left(\sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^N A_{mn}\;e_me_n^T\right)Z^T \\
 &= YAZ^T
}$$
where $y_m$ is the $m^{th}$ column of matrix $Y$,
and $z_n$ is the $n^{th}$ column of matrix $Z$,
and $A_{mn}$ are the elements of the matrix $A$.

In the current problem, $A$ is the identity matrix
and $\,y=z=(x-\mu),\;$ where $\,\mu=\tfrac 1N(X{\tt1})$ is the row-mean vector of $X$.

For typing convenience, define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
J &= \tfrac 1N {\tt1}{\tt1}^T \quad\implies\quad J^2=J=J^T \\
U &= \big[\mu\;\;\mu\;\;\ldots\;\mu \big]
 \;=\; \mu{\tt1}^T 
 \;=\;  XJ 
}$$
Then the sum can be expanded as
$$\eqalign{
\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)\,(x_n-\mu)^T 
  &= \sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^N \delta_{mn}\,(x_m-\mu)\,(x_n-\mu)^T \\
  &= (X-U)I(X-U)^T \\
  &= XX^T - UX^T - XU^T + UU^T \\
  &= XX^T - (XJ)X^T - X(J^TX^T) + XJ^2X^T \\
  &= XX^T - XJX^T \\
  &= X(I-J)X^T \\
  &= XCX^T \\
}$$